# Passing callbacks to C code from .NET, valid code or not?

Tags: .net, callback, pinvoke, marshalling

We have a .NET (c#) wrapper for a rather large C API. In this wrapper the user can provide a callback which is called repeatedly from the native code.

The callback looks like this :

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public delegate void LogCallBack(SlmStream str, string wtsr, IntPtr handle);
```

The user can input the callback through :

```
public void SetLoggingCallback(LogCallBack lcallback,
                               IntPtr      handle)
{
  SlmReturn ret = (SlmReturn)Native.SlmSetLoggingCallbackW(ModelPtr,
                                                           lcallback,
                                                           handle);

  if( ret != SlmReturn.SlmRetOk )
  {
    throw new SlmException(ret,ret.ToString());
  }
}
```

which is eventually calling :

```
[DllImport("sulum20.dll",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall , CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int SlmSetLoggingCallbackW(IntPtr      ModelPtr,
                                                LogCallBack lcallback,
                                                IntPtr      handle);
```

One user called the callback routine in the following way (simplified) :

```
string temp;
    SetLoggingCallback((str, wtsr, handle) => { temp = wtsr; Console.WriteLine(temp);  }, IntPtr.Zero);
```

This cause the application to crash on some platforms and not on others.

So my question remains, is this valid ?

Coming from the C/C++ world, one thing puzzles me :

Is it valid code to access instances of classes created outside the scope of the callback (i.e "string temp") ? I mean my guess would be that the marshalling need to have them as input/output parameters to be able to control it. I considered trying [marshalling on my own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7.aspx) by using the handle parameter, but not sure that was overkill or not.

UPDATE 1 :

Maybe this is what I need [GCHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.fromintptr%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) ?

UPDATE 2 :

The callback is called from the native code ala :

```
      if( logcallback_ != NULL )
      {
        (logcallback_)(cstream_,chbuf_,logcallbackhandle_);
      }
```

Update 3 :

With

```
  string temp;
               LogCallBack logCallback = (str, wtsr, handle) =>
                                             {
                                                 temp = "Hello";
                                             };
               smodel.SetLoggingCallback(logCallback, IntPtr.Zero);
```

It gives the same crash.

UPDATE 4 :

```
typedef void (ISLMCALL *SlmLogCallBackW)(enum SlmStream,const wchar_t*, void *handle);
```

UPDATE 5

Also tried and failed with :

```
 var logCallback = new LogCallBack(TargetMethod);
               smodel.SetLoggingCallback(logCallback, IntPtr.Zero);

    private string _test;

   private void TargetMethod(SlmStream str, IntPtr wtsr, IntPtr handle)
   {
       _test = "Hello";
   }
```

SOLUTION :

Use GCHandler to keep the delegate alive so it's not being garbage collected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your delegate:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public delegate void LogCallBack(SlmStream str, string wtsr, IntPtr handle);
```

First of all, I don't know what `SlmStream` is so I cannot comment on how it is marshalled. That's certainly a possible failure vector.

The `IntPtr` handle presents no issues. Presumably on the native side that is a pointer of some sort, perhaps `void*`.

The most obvious problem with the code then is the string parameter, `wtsr`. The marshaller assumes that you will pass a pointer to null terminated array of wide characters. In native terms that is `wchar_t*`. However, the marshaller also takes on responsibility for destroying the native memory. And it assumes that the memory was allocated from the COM heap and so calls `CoTaskMemFree`.

I think it likely that your native code does not allocate the null terminated character array on the COM heap. This would certainly explain crashes on some platforms but not others.

Here are a few ways to solve the issue:

1. Get the native code to allocate off the COM heap and let the managed code deallocate it.
2. If the native code allocates and deallocates, then declare the parameter in your delegate as `IntPtr` and call `Marshal.PtrToStringUni` in your delegate to convert to a managed string.

---

Your comments tell me that option 2 is the right solution. Your delegate should be:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public delegate void LogCallBack(SlmStream str, IntPtr wtsr, IntPtr handle);
```

And implement it like this:

```
(str, wtsr, handle) => { Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringUni(wtsr));  }
```

---

The other thing that you clearly have to do is make sure that the delegate is kept alive so that it still exists when the native code calls it.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the marshaller would actually also free the "string wtsr", that's certainly not what I want. It's an array of wchars but allocated in native and freed there too.

Comment: BTW : SlmStream is just a simple enum, no danger there.

Comment: Show the native declaration of `logcallback_`. Also, I cannot see any evidence that you changed your delegate. Could you use a real function rather than a lambda please to prove to me that you really did what I asked.

Comment: Updated the question to include the declaration. I can not change the lambda until in a couple of hours since it's joint work with another, who is not here now. Thanks for the help, will get back later.

Comment: So just to be clear it's valid to have the callback access temp like that ?

Comment: I cannot see that you changed the declaration of the delegate `LogCallBack` like I asked. Did you?

Comment: And for sake of completeness, show the declaration of `SlmStream`.

Comment: [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  public delegate void LogCallBack(SlmStream str, IntPtr wtsr, IntPtr handle);

Comment: #define ISLMCALL __stdcall

Comment: Take out that weird variable capture of `temp` then. Have an empty delegate. Then have a delegate like the one in my answer.

Comment: Empty delegate and a delegate just writing to a console works fine. Once you access temp then it all fails.

Comment: As updated above, we also tried without a lambda i.e normal function, which failed too.

Comment: OK, so the problem is variable capture. I can't see quite enough of the code to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I think this is a nice blog post explaining one problem with keeping the delegate alive and not being GC, that is not handled in above code. http://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/06/19/delegates-as-callbacks-part-2/

Comment: Yes, you've got to keep the delegate alive!

Comment: That seem to do the trick ! Thanks for all the helpful comments @DavidHefferhan